# Adding jar to the java build path, which is already existing in the server

Tags: java, eclipse, buildpath

I am creating a jar, which is refering `json.jar`. And this jar is already present in the server in a path `/appl/server/libpath`.

How do I refer this jar in my java project and export my new jar refering to it?

Comment: Most servers have a shared lib path that you can place existing libraries into. These libs will then be accessible by all the projects. What server are you using?

Comment: This depends on what build system is in use in your project. In case it's [maven](http://maven.apache.org/) then you should add a dependecy on a corresponding artifact and leave everything else including deployment to `maven`. If it's [ant](http://ant.apache.org/), then you should have that `json.jar` somewhere in the working tree of your project and add it to the `<classpath>` entry of `<javac>` directive and handle deployment somehow else (e.g. manually upload to the server new versions)

Comment: It depends from some conditions: current OS, current build and distribute system, current rights. Please, specify your environment

Comment: Hi, I am creating jar from eclipse.